# Can anyone please correct my given statement if its wrong(about throw/throws)

Tags: java, exception, throw, throws

`THROW`:-We have to handle the exception(we in the sense user here).

`Throws`:We are asking the compiler to handle the exception raised.

Please correct if what I stated above is wrong . If wrong please tell me the correct statement.

Thanks in Adv!

Comment: Are these quiz questions? Anyways, both are easily searchable. [`throw`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html). [`throws`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html).

Comment: @JasonC no they are not.i just wanted to know what I have understood is correct or wrong.so if u can please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that both are not *exact*.

[`throw`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html) statement causes throwing of exception. No-one *has* to catch it however. For example runtime exception can be thrown without any requirement to catch them in application code.

[`throws`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html) is a keyword that allows to declare that method *may* throw exception of specific type.

Comment: Adding to this, their usage is similar to their usage in English. If I say `throw the ball`, I am giving a command to do something (throw the ball). If I say that something `throws the ball`, I am declaring the action that something may take.

Comment: @Jason C, +1 for English meaning. I am afraid however that linguistics  does not help to OP too much.